# Visual Studio locks unnecessary projects during debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have a very large solution that contains many projects. I am trying to debug two processes at the same time:
A server and a client.

I compile the code, and then run the server process by pressing F5. All is well.

I now want to run my client process. To do that, I right-click the project, and press "Debug>Start new instance". 
This results in the error "CS2012: cannot open '.....GuiUtils\obj\debug\GuiUtils.dll' for writing - ..... because it is being used by another process."  However, the server has no dependency upon 'GuiUtils', and this library is also not present in the bin\debug folder of the server.

Not needless to say, I didn't update the source files of GuiUtils, so building it is futile regardless of this problem.

It seems like visual studio is using that DLL and locks it for no apparent reason.

Both projects are C# projects.

Help, anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Things are not quite what they seem.  Do note the path name, obj\Debug is not where your executable files are located.  They are in bin\Debug.  There is only ever one scenario that I can think of why anything in obj\Debug would be used at runtime.  Not the dll, the pdb.  The debugger uses that one when it can't find the pdb the normal way.  Use Debug > Windows > Modules in the server process and look where the PDBs came from.  Right-click and select Symbol Load Information.

Comment: @EZSlaver, You can use Process Explorer to find out which process hold your file, please also disable the Visual studio hosting process in your projects property.